# Undefined variable: pdo, call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was following a video and double checking all code and everything seems to be the same yet I get these errors.

**Errors**:

*Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in QueryBuilder.php on line 14*

*Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in QueryBuilder.php on line 14*

**QueryBuilder.php**:

```
class QueryBuilder
{
    protected $pdo;

    public function __construct($pdo)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function selectAll($table)
    {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `$table`"); // --> LINE 14 <--
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

**Connection.php**:

```
class Connection
{
    public static function make()
    {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $dbUsername = "root";
        $dbPassword = "";
        $dbName = "test";

        try {
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbName", $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            return $pdo;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**init.php**:

```
require "database/Connection.php";
require "database/QueryBuilder.php";
require "app/Product.php";

$query = new QueryBuilder(Connection::make());
```

Comment: `$table` that needs to be defined; it's a variable.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I do it in index.php, something like - `$products = $query->selectAll("products");`

Comment: Try `$query = $this->pdo->prepare`

Comment: @Fred-ii- `$query = $this->pdo->prepare` worked. You can post it as answer if you want. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, it has been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments, in OOP, you need to use `$this->pdo` passing the object's property for it, instead of the variable `$query = $pdo->` since you've construct'ed it in:

```
public function __construct($pdo)
{
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
    ^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

I.e.:

```
$query = $this->pdo->prepare
```